# TCP socket communication issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets, tcp

I'm a newbie in iOS programming - and I need a little help with resolving my problem...
I spent many hours trying to find a solution to this problem - but without any success...

I'm writing a very simple application (on iPad) which will send over a few TCP commands to my server. The server is already configured and working properly. I can connect to it with pTerm on my iPad, and after connecting succesfully over RAW TCP or telnet I can send the request to my server looking like that:

> `#100` <kbd>enter</kbd>

and it works..

But when Im trying to do it on my application - it doesn't work, it seems to be a problem with the end of line information to server (normally done by pushing <kbd>enter</kbd> key).
Server is configured on 192.168.1.220, port 2000.

After clicking reset button it should send command to server - but I can't see anything on the server side...

My .h file looks:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetbutton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewController;
- (IBAction)resetbuttonclick:(id)sender;

@end
```

my .m file :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize resetbutton;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [self setViewController:nil];
    [self setResetbutton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return YES;
}

- (void)initNetworkCommunication
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.1.220", 2000, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = objc_unretainedObject(readStream);
    outputStream = objc_unretainedObject(writeStream);
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void)sendMessage
{
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#100\n"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}

- (IBAction)resetbuttonclick:(id)sender
{
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
    [self sendMessage];
}

@end
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are initing the connection two times, remove the line `[self initNetworkCommunication];` from the `resetbutonclick` method.

Comment: Ok, I removed it. I checked also - that #100 is sent - but I dont know how to send end of line char - chr(13).When

Comment: When? So it is working now, but you want to send another character right? chr(13)?

Answer (score 0):

One thing one immediately notices is you don't have any stream event hadlers - which is strange. How do you know that connection had been established?

`- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode`

The code in [iPhone Network Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/0/page/1) is tested and working, if you're willing to read trough the articles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid such problems by using an additional library? (abstraction on top)
I use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket). It is very simple an comfortable.